# How to read "realize the mapping $x \cdot -: T \rightarrow T$"

Tags: category-theory, monoid

This question is about [Category theory for the sciences (by David Spivak)](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/CT4S.pdf).

In Exercise 3.1.2.4-a the set $T = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \; | \; 0 \leq x < 12\}$ needs to be defined using a coequalizer. I think this can be done using $Coeq(f,g)$ where $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x + 12$.

Then, part b is:

> For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, realize the mapping $x \cdot -: T \rightarrow T$, implied by Example 3.1.2.3, using
>   the universal property of coequalizers.

In part c I need to show that this is an action. Example 3.1.2.3 defines a set $S$ similar to $T$ but for natural numbers, and an action is defined which for a pair $(n, s)$ gives the remainder of dividing $n + s$ by 12.

This confuses me because in the context it seems an action would be of the form $R \times T \rightarrow T$. Also, I read $\cdot -$ as "times minus", and I don't think the conditions on an action hold when we do that with the additive monoid of real numbers.

I think the notation means something different from how I read it, maybe someone can help me read it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a minus, it's a dash. It indicates a blank.

Comment: Thanks (again), that helps a bit. I still don't understand though: the blank makes it sound as if the set element is dismissed? But the similar action on $n$ and $s$ does use $s$ and is described by $N \times S \rightarrow S$. I think I still just don't really understand what $x \cdot - : T \rightarrow T$ describes - what the colon denotes exactly, why there are two elements before it, if $\cdot$ has something to do with multiplication. I tried to look for a reference on notation in category theory but I can't really find what I need, googling on mathematical symbols is not so straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have for example a mapping $f : A \times B \to C$ and an $a\in A$, then $f(a,-)$ is the mapping: $$f(a,-) : B \to C, b \mapsto f(a,b)$$

In your case, we have:

$$x\cdot - : T \to T, t\mapsto x\cdot t$$

which ''comes'' from an $x\in R$ and the map $\cdot : R \times T \to T$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the notation. I'm still struggling though: the action on $n$ and $s$ was based on addition, not multiplication, but the monoid is still additive. Is there an online resource where I could read more about mappings and function notation? On wikipedia for example I cannot really find this information in the detail I need. Also I'm not sure if the $x \cdot -$ definition you give is a function of 2 arguments, or essentially a curried function with only one argument ($t$ or $x$?). I would love to be able to figure this all out more independently but answers are hard to find :)

Comment: Actually, I think the $\cdot$ might be a mistake in the book. I just found out that in a [newer version of the book](http://category-theory.mitpress.mit.edu/chapter004.html) it has been replaced by $+$. Still, background resources on function notation/mappings would be more than welcome.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden Yes, those are basically curried functions in one argument, as indicated by the $B \to C$ or $T\to T$. I don't know a specific source .Basically every well-known category theory book uses notation like this: "Category theory" by Steve Awodey, "Handbook of categorical algebra"  by Francis Borceux, "Basic Category Theory" by Tom Leinster, not to mention "Categories for the working mathematician" by Saunders MacLane, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will see if I can get access to one of those. The reason I'm using Spivak's book is that it's written for a broader audience (I'm not a mathematician), I'm worried the other books will be a bit inaccessible to me.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden "Basic category theory" by Tom Leinster is imo the best way to start. It's also quite short.